# Get number from regular expression and add that number of spaces

Tags: php, regex

```html
<p style="margin-left:5px"><em>6.1. pH changes</em></p>
```

I want to get `5` (which can be any number) of `5px` add that number of spaces after `<p><em>`
tag.

I have used the following but to no avail.

```php
$result = preg_replace('#<p style="margin-left:[\s]?\.([0-9])[0-9]?in"><em>#','<p><em>[&nbsp;]{$1}',$string);
```

please help in this regard. will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: You can not use `{$1}` in the replacement and expect it to mean repetition there – that’s not how it works. You could use `preg_replace_callback` and then pass the number to a function that uses `str_repeat` to create the five non-breaking spaces.

Comment: **DONT PARSE HTML WITH REGEXES**

Comment: can you put an example here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
$result = preg_replace_callback('#<p\s*style="margin-left:(?P<SpaceCount>[0-9]+)[^>]*><em>#', function($matches) { return '<p><em>' . str_repeat('&nbsp;', intval($matches['SpaceCount'])); }, '<p style="margin-left:5px"><em>6.1. pH changes</em></p>');
```

Comment: You should not advice others to parse HTML with regexes

Comment: That won’t work – the second parameter will be evaluated _before_ it is passed to preg_replace, so str_repeat will be called before $1 even contains a value. You will have to use `preg_replace_callback` as I mentioned in my comment.

Comment: @CBroe I though that might be the case, I don't work with PHP so I told him to try, but thank you.

Comment: @CBore is right, it was causing problems. I have modified your answer according to my needs and it works fine, the way I wanted. Thank you for your precious time :)

Comment: @hek2mgl why should not be done this way, if so what's your solution then?

Comment: @TestKhan My solution would be to use `DOMDocument`

Comment: @hek2mgl As I said before I totally agree with you.

Comment: @TestKhan In general you should always use HTML parser when you are working with HTML, or more generally don't use regex to parse structures that can be nested inside each other.